# First product is NULL in Magento

Tags: magento

Every time I query something like

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

The returned array has the 0th element of `NULL`.

For example the product names are

```
array(2) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> string(23) "test product21958843964" }
```

Why? It drives me crazy, as this 'ghost product' is not even showing up in admin panel. And filtering the array manually wouldn't be the safest solution for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be imported product with programmatically, you need to check catalog_product_entity table, is there any entry for that.